# Getting A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. while trying to connect with Outlook mail

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm trying to connect with Outlook mail
have implemented the connections but authentication is getting failed, have given the username and password but still getting that issue.

Here is the the java code I have written, how can I have to get authentication success?

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();

props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");

props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);

mailSession.setDebug(true);
Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "mail", "password");
```

Comment: Can you add error log on your question?